# While loop is not stopping and reading last line (bash)

Tags: bash, while-loop

code snippet is below i'm simply trying to curl url details but loops is acting weirdly it's not ending the loop properly if more than 2 urls has been provided to text file & if one url is provided than not able to read that with out this line `|| [ -n url ]`.

```
while IFS= read -r url || [ -n url ] ; do
    sh file.sh $url
done < "file.txt"
```

Comment: `[ -n url ]` is always true, because the string `u` `r` `l` is not empty. You may have wanted to write `[ -n "$url" ]`. Also, I am not certain that `||` is logically correct.

Comment: @AlexP, the `||` *is* good logic -- we want to loop as long as either the `read` reports success, or it populated the variable otherwise (as will happen if the file has extra contents after its last complete line -- of course, the better fix is to correct the file's formatting so all text is followed by a newline). But you're right about the OP needing to use `[ -n "$url" ]`.

Comment: Also,  of course, the OP should also be running `./file.sh "$url"`, with the quotes around the expansion, and probably putting a `</dev/null` on that inner command so it doesn't consume their stream from `file.txt`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: But `$url` will remain set from the previous iteration, won't it?

Comment: @AlexP, no -- it populates the destination variable with the partial line's content even when it returns false.

Comment: @AlexP Thank you for correcting my mistake

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah just check it was asked before. Thank you to for assistance